# Select option in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Select extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      values: "testing"
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event){
    this.setState({values: event.target.value});
    this.props.onSelect(this.state.values);
    console.log("valus is " +this.state.values + " event is " + event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <select value={this.state.values} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="">
            Select one...
          </option>
          {this.props.question.map(obj => (
            <option key={obj.id} value={obj.percentage}>
                {obj.question}
            </option>
          ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

Right now I am creating a select menu, the default selecting value is empty. there is here option here (select one = "", question1= "1", 
question2=2) I have no idea why I chick question1, it consoles the value 
is the previous one "testing", but the event.target.value is correct. 
Someone can give me a help? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour your are noticing is due to the `setState()` method [being asynchronous](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3). To log the updated state to console, consider doing this via the callback for `setState()`, which is called when the state change has been applied to the component:

```
handleChange(event){

    this.setState({values: event.target.value}, () => {
        console.log("valus is " + this.state.values + 
                    " event is " + event.target.value);
    });

    this.props.onSelect(this.state.values);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As Dacre stated this.setState is asynchronous. A cleaner way to fix this is with async-await.

```js
class Select extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      values: "testing"
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  async handleChange(event){
    await this.setState({values: event.target.value});
    this.props.onSelect(this.state.values);
    console.log("valus is " +this.state.values + " event is " + event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <select value={this.state.values} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="">
            Select one...
          </option>
          {this.props.question.map(obj => (
            <option key={obj.id} value={obj.percentage}>
                {obj.question}
            </option>
          ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but setState doesn't return a promise